# Pass context values outside of React tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, azure-ad-msal

I am setting up a new React project using the newest version of React Router.The docs state that `createBrowserRouter` needs to be called outside of the React tree [docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router).

My problem is that I need to get some context values to either pass as a prop into my `loader` functions. Or I need to pass those context values directly to the function.

Here is the Router implementation:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <AppLayout />,
    id: 'root',
    loader: () => defaulNewAPIs(),
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
        path: '/:appTypeId?/:submissionId?',
        loader: ({ params }) => {
          const { appTypeId, submissionId } = params as ReferralParams
          if (appTypeId && submissionId) {
            return getSubmission(params)
          }
          return null
        },
      },
    ],
  },
])

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <GenReMsal>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <AuthenticatedTemplate>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </AuthenticatedTemplate>
      <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        <GenReLogin />
      </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </GenReMsal>
)
```

`GenReMsal` is an implementation of the Msal-React package and functions as a context provider. I can access those context values by wrapping a React component in `withMsal()`.

For example my `AppLayout` function accesses that context as follows:

```
const AppLayout: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ msalContext }: AppProps) => {
  const { appTypeId } = useParams()
  const currentUser = { name: msalContext.accounts[0].name }

  return (
    <>
      {!appTypeId && (
        <AppHeader
          appName="REFERRALS"
          currentUser={currentUser}
          notificationNumber="4"
        />
      )}
      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}

export default withMsal(AppLayout)
```

I need to somehow get this context value in my root file so it can be used in the default `loader` function. Alternatively, I could find a way to wrap `defaultNewAPIs` in the context.

This function lives in a folder with several other exported api calls and is not part of a React component.